# Why scopes in general do not have prologue and epilogue instructions?

Tags: cpu, assembly, instruction-set

Data only accessible in a scope, seems to still be maintained by the stack. What is the reason that entering and exiting scopes (in general) does not do the same ["prologue and epilogue" instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue_and_epilogue) that are done when entering and exiting functions?

What test1 and test2 show, in test2 8 byte is allocated in the stack, but it has already left the scope for `int a` when declaring `int b`. The ISA is x86 (compiled on godbolt.org with x86-64) but I assume this behavior might exist in many different standards, and ask from a more general computer science point of view.

```
void test1(){
    int a;
    { a = 141; }
    a = 257;
}

test1():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 141
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 257
    nop
    pop     rbp
    ret

void test2(){
    { int a = 141; }
    int b = 257;
}

test2():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 141
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 257
    nop
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Comment: It is weird that the compiler did implement at all the first assignments to `a`, which should have been optimized away.

Comment: I thought about that too, I just assumed compilers tended to push variables to stack "in case" the programmer intended to use them. I'm very very new to code at machine instruction / assembly level.

Comment: A good optimising compiler should have not generated ANY code for the variables or assignments as these functions return no results and have no side effects and so all instructions can be optimised down to a single `ret`.....

Comment: If I add compiler option -O it does compile down to just ret. I assume -O is optimization, -O3 also works, don't know exact format. Thanks for comments, now I got to see good example of using optimization vs not.

Comment: In fact, aggressive optimizers avoid instructions "in case" as much as possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's what I would assume they do, but since I'm new to compilers, and I assumed they would do that to start with (without optimization flag), I assumed it must be for some reason. Thanks for your comments overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made an assumption about scopes in the C language which is not correct.

Unlike general Algol family languages, C does not have infinitely nested scopes for every statement block. Although your have used the brackets `{}` inside a function, you have not created a new scope. the only scope present is that of the function, and the prologue and epilogue only exist to create new scopes for the function itself.

In languages that have more generalised scoping rules that permit classes inside classes and functions nested inside functions and blocks are the equivalent of anonymised functions, then yes your would have a new scope. However not in the language you chose to do your test. In, say Algol 68, you would have made a new scope like you were trying to test!

Comment: Thanks. That sounds good, that my assumption would be true in some languages like Algol. I was hoping something like that was the case (so I could verify I was at least thinking a bit right about how the computer was working, I am very early in my learning and good to know I was not entirely off track. )

Comment: That the brackets make "int a" inaccessible from the overall test1 scope, if it is not a new scope, is there an explanation to that?

Comment: [Blocks do create scopes in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope).

Comment: @m90 but do not create a new activation record. Scope changed in C99, but it is only lexical. perhaps I should have been more detailed an pedantic

Answer (score 1):

At every point in time, the space on the stack must be large enough to handle all variables that are in scope. And you generally don't want to use more stack space than needed to avoid wasting space.

Now lets say you required 104 bytes of stack space before entering a scope, and 108 bytes are required within the scope. If you make the stack space always 108 bytes you waste 4 bytes of stack space while not in scope. However, if you need to change it from 104 to 108 bytes, you need instructions to increase, and then to decrease the stack size, and these instructions take space as well. These instructions even take space if you never enter the scope, or the whole function.

So its a balancing act: Do you want to save stack space, or do you want to save instructions? Having "int a;" vs. "int a[10000];" in the scope would make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks, all very good points about the tradeoffs. As a beginner, answers like these help a lot. The other answer by Bryan Tompsett mentioned C languages do not treat blocks between brackets as scope (other than in "lexical" sense since C99. ) This seems to imply that although prologue and epilogue instructions might be occasionally wasteful, as you describe very well, they might be excluded by default or design in C languages even when a block is large enough to warrant them?